# Can I tie an anonymous function to a Timer's tick event?

Tags: c#, timer

If a Tick-handling function will only be used in one context (i.e. always in the same function in combination with the same Timer object), why bother make it a separate function? That's the thought that went through my head when I thought of this.

Is it possible to tie an anonymous function to a Timer's tick event? Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(function(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're looking for [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
myTimer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
};
```

You can also omit the parameters:

```
myTimer.Tick += delegate {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
};
```

In C# 3.0, you can also use a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
myTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
};
```

Answer (score 7):

A complete example would be:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 500;
    timer.Tick += (t, args) =>
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            /* some code */
        };
    timer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

You use the `delegate` keyword for anonymous methods:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
};
```

In C# 3.0 and later, you can also use lambdas:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
```

Comment: You can use lambda expressions in .Net 2.0.  You mean **C#** _3.0_.